# Drag file into Jquery sortable list at a specific position

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a Jquery sortable list which has a drop event associated to it. When I drag a file (from my Docs folder) onto the list, it currently appends a new item to it. I can then sort it within that list fine.

Is there a way to get the position within the sortable list, of where I dropped the file, so I can insert the new item at that position instead of the bottom of it?

I've looked at the evt.clientX and clientY properties, but they return values such as 400 and 342, which don't help identify which li elements that is before or after.

Thanks

Comment: add a function that appends a number into li class which you can use as a selector later and use split function to get the list item number? I might add that you may also need a fucntion that would change those numbers every time you add a new element, so they go in the right sequence.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I'll have a go at that